# SQL server to Snowflake load

Tags: sql-server, ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am loading data from SQL Server to Snowflake through SSIS (Visual Studio 2015-32 bit being used here). I am able to load data successfully when the table exist only in one database. But whenever the same table with same columns exist in two databases (like Staging and Datawarehouse db), it is unable to identify which db table to be used. When i type the name of table in ODBC destination instead of selecting from drop down and the go to mappings page, the mapping tab does not come up at all.

Kindly help me resolve this issue. Please do let me know if you need any further details

Comment: Check your connection strings for source and destination. They specifically navigate to a database.

Comment: Also, I find OLEDB connections are easier to work with.

Comment: i specify the database to connect to but its not picking up the right database, there is no OLEDB connection for snowflake data warehouse

Comment: For each connection, if you are setting a database you may need to call "use database" to see the other table - though I am not sure how your software manages the connection. Make sure the driver version is the 32 bit version. ref: https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008DCrSRSA1/how-to-connect-to-snowflake-with-ssis and https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake

Comment: Have you seen this forum post which looks almost exactly like the question being asked?  https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00009Z3SfmSAF/loading-data-from-sql-server-to-snowflake

Comment: Yes but that forum doesn’t help with the solution